# compile jquery chosen file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the 'blur' event to work using a jquery chosen listbox.  I found a 'hack' adds this event to the chosen .js file.
I added the code to chosen.jquery.js that is in my VS2010 project.  But I need to recompile it to see if these changes will do the trick.

How do I recompile the .js chosen file?

Thanks.

Comment: JavaScript is an interpreted language...?  Are you asking how to incorporate the code from this event hack into the script you already have?

Comment: yes.  I thought it would need to be compiled.  I added the 2 functions into the .js file.

Comment: It should just work when you refresh the page, if you've done everything right.

Comment: I added it to the file chosen.jquery.js.  In my Page.Master file, I had a link to chosen.jquery.min.js.  Would I have to add a link to chosen.jquery.js?

Comment: It is not working.  So I will have to do something else other than 'blur'

Comment: FYI, jQuery supports blur events:  https://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: jquery does...but the jquery-chosen plugin does not.  I could not get it to work so I am trying something else.

Comment: Did you fix the issue??
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643721/chosen-files-are-not-coming-up-in-my-assets-jquery-chosen-in-rails

Please have a check here and see If you could help